# Abrir y cerrar un plot dentro de un while

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy tratando de graficar una señal con Matplotlib y el plot se encuentra dentro de un `while`. Lo que quiero es que cada vez que pase por el `while` se abra una gráfica y luego ya sea enseguida o pasado un tiempo que yo pueda controlar esta se cierre. Tengo algo mas o menos así , pero no funciona.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Ciclo import ciclo

b = ciclo()

g = []

pin = 1

while (True):

    val = b.cicloHigh(pin)
    t = t + 1
    res = int((int(val)*250000)/1023)
    g.append(res)
    print("%s ............... %s"%(res, t))
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(g)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Debido a que `plt.show()` es un ciclo entonces nunca se cierra a menos que sea manual.

Y quiero que se abra y se cierre de una vez o si es posible que se cierre en cierto tiempo, pero no logro ninguna de las dos formas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, lo que dices que te pasa es que el programa se para en `plt.show()` y que lo que quieres es que siga con la siguiente iteración. Para ello se le puede pasar un argumento indicándole que no se bloquee:

```
plt.show(block=False)
```

Si no resuelve el problema, añade alguna explicación más de lo que quieres.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando lo que ha escrito @ChemaCortes, te falta alguna cosa más. Por hacerlo de forma simple, he incluido comentarios en un ejemplo más abajo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep

y = np.random.randn(10)

while True: # Bucle infinito que puedes cerrar con crtl+c
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.show(block = False) # Para que no se congele la ejecución
    sleep(2) # La imagen se mostrará 2 segundos.
    plt.close(1)  # Es importante que indiques qué vas a cerrar
                  # En plt.figure he usado 1 para darle un índice a la figura
                  # En plt.close indico ese índice para saber qué hay que cerrar
    sleep(1) # esperamos 1 segundo para generar la nueva imagen.
```

Saludos.

Comment: Sí, esta respuesta está mucho mejor. ¿Por qué creas un bucle infinito con `while 1 < 2` en vez de `while True` simplemente?

Comment: Pues también es verdad ;-)

Comment: @ChemaCortes además, por curiosidad, he hecho un mini test de rendimiento y es un 30% peor (como era de esperar), así que he modificado la respuesta para cambiar la condición.